# Sort the grid view after merging cells using OnDataBound asp:net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
private void GridViewBind()
{
    SqlConnection Dbcon = new SqlConnection();
    Dbcon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
    "ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    Dbcon.Open();

    string expSql = "SELECT [dName],[item],[cnt] FROM [Test1].[dbo].[Test3]
    ORDER BY [dName], [cnt] desc";
    SqlDataAdapter adAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(expSql, Dbcon);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adAdapter.Fill(ds);

    GridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView.DataBind();

    ViewState["dt"] = ds.Tables[0];
    ViewState["sort"] = "Desc";
}
```

I drew a table using gridview(asp:gridview) And I made a db for test and bound it
Then, in order to merge cells with the same subject, cells were merged using OnDataBound.

I want to sort by merged subject when cnt is clicked
However, my sort code sorts the entire cnt column, and the merged cells are unraveled.

I need a way to keep the merged cells and do ASC/DESC sorting within them!

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = GridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[i]; 
        GridViewRow previousRow = GridView2.Rows[i - 1];
        int j = 0;
        if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
        {
            if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
            {
                if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                {
                    previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                row.Cells[j].Visible = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment, so i comment here in answer.
Can you add your OnDataBound code where your merged subject?
Also can you make your select query with merged subject as column, then you just need to bind data directly to gridview.

For sorting you can follow below link:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/paging-and-sorting-in-Asp-Net-gridview/

https://codepedia.info/gridview-sorting-header-click

Comment: OnDataBound was added. However, if you do a normal sort, the cells merged with OnDataBound are split